# Add an edge between two labeled vertices only if another edge of the same label doesn't exist?

Tags: traversal, gremlin

My `traversal`:

```
g.V(id1).as("entity")
 .V(id2).as("type1")
 .addE("hasType").from("entity").to("type1");
```

I would like to change it so it only adds this edge if another edge of the same `edgeLabel` doesn't already exist between the same vertices.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This uses the where step see if there is an incoming edge from "entity" (from the perspective of "type1") before proceeding.

```
g.V(id1).as("entity").
  V(id2).as("type1").
  not(__.in("hasType").where(eq("entity"))).
  addE("hasType").from("entity").to("type1")
```

Comment: Thank you! I think it needs ```not()``` right? Also could I use ```where()``` step in the case of my other question http://stackoverflow.com/q/41314091/986160 ?

Comment: I tried your query as is and it never adds any edges.. I tried with ```where(neq("entity")))``` and it is adding edges all the time.. so I am not sure what's wrong :(

Comment: Replace `where(__.in("hasType").where(eq("entity")))` with `not(__.in("hasType").where(eq("entity")))` and it should work as expected.

Comment: So sorry about that. I tested the query up to but not including the addE() step.

Comment: @PaulJackson can you please edit so I can accept! thanks