# how to add a vertex only if it doesn't exist and continue this single traversal with other graph mutations?

Tags: gremlin

Currently I have this gremlin/groovy code:

```
if(!g.V().has("Number","number","3").hasNext()) {
   g.addV("Number").property("number","3")
}
```

Is it possible to have the same result without using multiple traversals?

I tried this and it doesn't work (it doesn't add either Number or User vertices)

```
g.V().choose(has("Number","number", "3"),
        addV("Number").property("number", "3"),
        has("Number","number", "3")
    ).as("number")
   .addV("User").property("uuid","test uuuid")
   .forEachRemaining(System.out::println);
```

I tried what it was suggested here (https://stackoverflow.com/a/33965737/986160) but it doesn't allow me to continue my single traversal with adding another user in a single transaction for DSE:

```
g.V()
 .has("Number","number", "3")
.tryNext()
.orElseGet(
   () -> g.addV("Number")
          .property("number", "3").next()
 );
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately we don't have `g.coalesce()` yet, but there's a workaround:

```
gremlin> g = TinkerGraph.open().traversal()
==>graphtraversalsource[tinkergraph[vertices:0 edges:0], standard]
gremlin> g.inject(1).coalesce(V().has("Number", "number", 3), addV("Number").property("number", 3))
==>v[0]
gremlin> g.inject(1).coalesce(V().has("Number", "number", 3), addV("Number").property("number", 3))
==>v[0]
gremlin> g.inject(1).coalesce(V().has("Number", "number", 3), addV("Number").property("number", 3))
==>v[0]
gremlin> g.V().valueMap()
==>[number:[3]]
```

Comment: ```1``` in ```inject(1)``` is a unique number for the traversal ? What if I have multiple createIfnotExists of different numbers? Can I do 
```g.inject(1).coalesce(V().has("Number", "number", 3), addV("Number").property("number", 3)).inject(1).coalesce(V().has("Number", "number", 4), addV("Number").property("number", 4));``` ? or do I need to do ```inject(2)```? Thanks

Comment: It's just something that keeps the traversal alive, even if `V().has("Number", "number", 3)` emits nothing. Could be `g.inject("michail")`.

Comment: could I also do somewhere just that  ```GraphTraversal<Vertex,Vertex> traversal = g.inject();```? and then continue with ```coalesce()``` somewhere else in the code?

Comment: It has to be something (not null).

Comment: The `inject` step is only necessary to prevent all taversers from dying. Mid-traversal you will most likely not have the same  problem.

Comment: is there a way to detect  in the java code if it actually existed or not while using the ```coalesce()```?

Comment: Also what if I want to build coalescence  list gradually with code? is there a way to do that? Thanks!

Comment: You can fill an array and use that as the only parameter.

Comment: Hi again.. this approach seems very painful when I need to have all the code to be coalesce'd before hand.. isn't there a way to know what happened in the database (did the vertex exist or not) so I can continue building my traversal? Are there any plans/implementations that make this more user-friendly? Is there a way that I can inject a lambda function to happen after the coalesce? My use case is vertex exists do stuff on it.. vertex doesn't exist, create it, do some other stuff on it in a single traversal/transaction

Comment: what if I want to do (if exists) (do something) (otherwise do something else)?

Comment: Unfortunately I get java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The provided traverser does not map to a value: e[198][194-CreatedBy->10]->[SelectOneStep(superentity-79990578-4525-4b8a-b1a5-9fb970d192e0), NoOpBarrierStep(2500)] when I try to do things after `coalesce()`